# Kubernetes service is reachable from node but not from my machine

Tags: kubernetes

I have a timeout problem with my site hosted on Kubernetes cluster provided by DigitalOcean.

```
u@macbook$ curl -L fork.example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to fork.example.com port 80: Operation timed out
```

I have tried everything listed on the [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working) page. I use a k8s service named `df-stats-site`.

```
u@pod$ nslookup df-stats-site
Server:     10.245.0.10
Address:    10.245.0.10#53

Name:   df-stats-site.deepfork.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.245.16.96
```

It gives the same output when I do it from node:

```
u@node$ nslookup df-stats-site.deepfork.svc.cluster.local 10.245.0.10
Server:     10.245.0.10
Address:    10.245.0.10#53

Name:   df-stats-site.deepfork.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.245.16.96
```

With the help of ***Does the Service work by IP?*** part of the page, I tried the following command and got the expected output.

```
u@node$ curl 10.245.16.96
*correct response*
```

Which should mean that everything is fine with DNS and service. I confirmed that `kube-proxy` is running with the following command:

```
u@node$ ps auxw | grep kube-proxy
root  4194  0.4  0.1 101864 17696 ?    Sl Jul04  13:56 /hyperkube proxy  --config=...
```

But I have something wrong with `iptables` rules:

```
u@node$ iptables-save | grep df-stats-site
(unfortunately, I was not able to copy the output from node, see the screenshot below)
```

[image: screenshot]

It is recommended to restart `kube-proxy` with with the `-v` flag set to 4, but I don't know how to do it with DigitalOcean provided cluster.

That's the configuration I use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: df-stats-site
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8002
  selector:
    app: df-stats-site

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: df-stats-site
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fork.example.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  rules:
  - host: fork.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: df-stats-site
          servicePort: 80
```

Also, I have a NGINX Ingress Controller set up with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968709/7211294).

I must note that it worked fine before. I'm not sure what caused this, but restarting the cluster would be great, though I don't know how to do it without removing all the resources.

Comment: What type of service is it?  LoadBalancer?  I'm assuming fork.example.com is a placeholder and your real domain has been configured so fork.yourdomain.com is pointing to the external ip of your service?

Comment: @frankd it's a ClusterIP.

Comment: Can you provide outpuf of `$ kubectl get svc -owide` and `$ kubectl get ingress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to add HTTP and HTTPS inbound rules in the Firewall (these are missing by default).

For DigitalOcean provided Kubernetes cluster, you can open it at https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/firewalls/.

**UPDATE:** Make sure to create a new firewall record rather than editing an existing one. Otherwise, your rules will be automatically removed in a couple of hours/days, because DigitalOcean k8s persists the set of rules in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

ClusterIP services are only accessible from within the cluster.  If you want to access it from outside the cluster, it needs to be configured as [NodePort or LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/).

If you are just trying to test something locally, you can use [kubectl port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to forward a port on your local machine to a ClusterIP service on a remote cluster.  Here's an example of creating a deployment from an image, exposing it as a ClusterIP service, then accessing it via kubectl port-forward:

```
$ kubectl run --image=rancher/hello-world hello-world --replicas 2
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=ClusterIP --port=8080 --target-port=80
$ kubectl port-forward svc/hello-world 8080:8080
```

This service is now accessible from my local computer at http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: ClusterIP worked fine, I use an Ingress entity to open the service to the outside world.

Comment: You got Ingress working without a LoadBalancer service?  Are you sure?  Cluster IP services are not accessible outside of a cluster. All ingress solutions I've seen use an Ingress Controller (which is a deployment) which is made accessible outside of the cluster by a LoadBalancer service.  Just adding an Ingress entity won't do anything and will not make your ClusterIP Service accessible outside the cluster.  Can you clarify for future readers of this question.

Comment: And to clarify, all of your application services can (and should) be ClusterIP if you are using ingress, but the Ingress Controller is exposed by a LoadBalancer.

Comment: I have it without LoadBalancer. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968709/7211294